# fetch dynamically modified html content from page using ob_start and ob_get_clean()

Tags: php

Here's the situation. I need to fetch a page and execute the javascript.. then process the page in PHP. That javascript dynamically modifies the HTML of the page. Here's what I'm thinking of doing.

- 1) Fetching the content using cURL/file_get_contents.
- 2) Print the content so that Javascript gets executed.
- 3) Use `ob_start` and `ob_get_clean` to fetch the modified content.

Code:

```
$contents = file_get_contents('http://...');
ob_start();
echo $contents;
$output = ob_get_clean();
```

Is there a way to achieve what I am attempting to do? I know javascript usually executes after page has loaded (and PHP is long gone).

Comment: things that make you go hmmmm

Comment: I have the source code for a page that i need to execute JS on and fetch back the results. I don't even necessarily have to fetch the results back as long as i can fetch a hidden value. so.. im thinking iframes..

Comment: you need to send the content-length header. Then the browser will begin to parse the js after the bytes are all read. (but the PHP script will continue

Comment: mind providing a snippet?

Answer (score 0):

`jQuery` with `.ajax()`, or the `XMLHttpRequest` Object with plain `JavaScript`.

Comment: yeah i guess ill have to go down that route